# How do I reset UIScrollView to Zeroth Page/Index when Clicking on a Tab Bar Item?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, scrollview

I have a tab bar application with 3 tabs. The first tab loads a UIImageView that is nested within a paginated ScrollView. If the user were to scroll through the pages for a bit, then click on another tab, and then click back to the first tab, they would return to the last page they scrolled to within the ScrollView.

How can I have make my first tab bar item resets to the initial image/page in my UIImageView every time it's clicked?

Thanks!

Comment: Setting the scrollview to the first page in `viewWillAppear:` is not good enough?

Comment: Nope, that method won't work because the users has the option of initializing a 'MFMailComposeViewController' within the ScrollView, and when the email is sent/saved/cancelled, it returns the user back to the first page (if I use your solution), which is not what I want to happen when they send an email. It should only happen when they click on the first tab bar item.

Comment: Then look into `UITabBarControllerDelegate`.

Comment: Right, I have been, but I'm so new to iOS development that I'm not sure how to tell it to do what I need it to do. I think it has something to do with `- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {}`

Comment: In `tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:` you can use the view controller parameter to check whether the first tab bar is about to be selected. If that is the case, set your scrollview to the first page. In any case, just return `YES` to allow the selection to proceed as normal.

Comment: If possible, could I get a code sample?

Comment: Figured it out using the shouldSelectViewController. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at :
[UITabBarControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITabBarControllerDelegate). You have a callback didSelectViewController.
One solution would be for your ApplicationDelegate to get this callback and inform your firstviewcontroller from the first tab to call a method that would just take the user to the first page.

Comment: THat's what I'm trying to do, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Figured it out using the shouldSelectViewController. Thanks!